# How to find and delete a service in InitializeSetup section using inno setup script

Tags: windows, service, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

Right now i am using

```
[UninstallRun]

Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "stop service" ; 
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "delete service" ;
```

but i want to check whether a  particular service is installed at the beginning of installation, if yes then `uninstall` it.

Thanks in Advance!